# Function to insert values in a column with a condition coming from another table

Tags: sql-server

I want to add a column (which is now NULL) to a table `[AllChurners]` that contains a list of Customer_IDs. This column has to display the value 1 if the `Customer_ID` matches one in a list of Customer_IDs in another table `[ListChurnerOrNot]`, 0 otherwise.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT 
    [CustID], [ChurnerOrNot]
    CASE
        WHEN [db].[dbo].[ListChurnerOrNot].CustID = [niccolo].[dbo].[AllChurners].CustID 
           THEN (INSERT INTO [db].[dbo].[ListChurnerOrNot] (ChurnerOrNot)
                 VALUES (1))
           ELSE (INSERT INTO [db].[dbo].[ListChurnerOrNot] (ChurnerOrNot)
                 VALUES (0))
    END
FROM 
    [db].[dbo].[AllChurners];
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you wanting to permanently store this computed result (usually not a good idea) or just to add an extra column when querying the data (doesn't involve `INSERT`).

Comment: Permanently store is fine, as I need to extract the table later on

Comment: So what happens as soon as the data in the other table is changed>#

Comment: I need to add other variables to the table to list a series of parameters describing the CustID

Comment: This is starting to smell like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: `CASE` is T-SQL is an **expresssion** that must return a single, atomic value - it's **NOT** a construct to optionally execute one block of code (or another) .... for that, just use `IF .... ELSE ...` statements

Comment: Ok I see, so I can explain the need. I have a list of IDs which are defined as churners, and a bigger list of IDs where there are churners and non-churners. I need a flag in the bigger list which says if the customer ID is a churner or not. Is it now clear?

Comment: SELECT [CustID], [ChurnerOrNot]
FROM [db].[dbo].[ListChurnerOrNot]
IF [db].[dbo].[ListChurnerOrNot].CustID = [db].[dbo].[AllChurners].CustID 
 INSERT INTO [db].[dbo].[ListChurnerOrNot] (ChurnerOrNot)
 VALUES (1);
ELSE INSERT INTO [db].[dbo].[ListChurnerOrNot] (ChurnerOrNot)
 VALUES (0);

You mean like that? it says "The multi-part identifier "niccolo.dbo.ListChurnerOrNot.NumeroTessera" could not be bound.
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update an existing column called 'ChurnerOrNot' in the [AllChurners] table by setting it's value to 1 or 0 depending on the presence of Customer_id in the [ListChurnerOrNot] table, you could do something like this

```
update ac
set ChurnerOrNot=case when lc.Customer_id is not null then 1 else 0 end
from [AllChurners] ac
     left join [ListChurnerOrNot] lc on ac.Customer_id=lc.Customer_id;
```